MongoDB wildcard in nested field selector
I have the following types in typescript.
type Student = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  score: number;
  // ...
}

type Class = {
  name: string;
  // key = student.id
  students: Record<string, Student>
}

For example,
const mathClass: Class = {
  name: "Math Class",
  students: {
    "S01": {
      id: "S01",
      name: "Alice",
      score: 88
    },
    "S02": {
      id: "S02",
      name: "Bob",
      score: 79
    }
  }
}      

and I insert this into MongoDB.
When I need to perform filtering, is it possible to make a query to select students with score higher than 80? Something like
db.classes.find({"students.*.score": {$gte: 80}})

I prefer not to use aggregation ($objectToArray) unless that's the only way.

guess youll have to use objectToArray

Does this answer your question? MongoDB wildcard in the key of a query

And generally, consider changing the student objects of <id>: <object which includes id> to an array of <object which includes id>. Then your query could have been db.classes.find({"students.score": {$gte: 80}}). Btw, that gives you the classes where at least one student got >= 80. If you wanted only the student who had that score, you would need to do an $unwind + $match, which only works on arrays anyway. But quite straightforward: https://mongoplayground.net/p/2uSYYz09SYF. Or filtered: https://mongoplayground.net/p/eD36z0XvXKH

I guess I will just go for objectToArray. There are some reasons to use nested object instead of array in my case. Thanks guys.
